# asp.net data entry static grid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am in the process of creating a data entry applications and I have a sample of what I would like it to look like and function. I what like a grid that is static and you can click in cells to edit. I have enclosed a pictures of what I would like it to look it. Can someone tell me how this was created?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a .net [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) using [row commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to add/update/delete.

Here is an example using a sql database:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" RunAt="Server" DataSourceID="sqlGrid" DataKeyNames="RowID" AllowPaging="False" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="False" GridLines="None" BorderWidth="0">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Col1" DataField="Col1" SortExpression="Col1"/>
    <asp:BoundField runat="Server" HeaderText="Col2" DataField="Col2" SortExpression="Col2"/>
    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True"/>
    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True"/>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlGrid" RunAt="Server" SelectCommand="spGrid" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" UpdateCommand="spGridUpdate" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="spGridDelete" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Col1" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Col2" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="RowID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

To type directly in the grid use [TemplateFields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb288032.aspx) to insert text boxes in your cells. Clicking save would submit the contents of the cell back to your database.

---

### Create blank row

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col1" SortExpression="Col1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TexBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TexBox >
        <asp:TexBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TexBox >
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

---

### WORKFLOW

1. Create database/table/columns.
2. Create stored procedures to read/edit/delete database data.
3. Create gridview with template fields and textboxes.
4. Populate data in gridview using your stored procedures.
5. Use sqlDataSource and row commands to update your data from the gridview.

Comment: Thank you @Obsidian, I guess that answers my question part way. The basic workflow would be: They click new record and the entire empty grid comes up with the static time values column and they could click save to save there progress and complete to close the form and they would have to click new record to start a new one. Also, the row commands would work to instantly insert the items. So basicly using the datagrid as a form, it will never get values from the database only insert. I hope that makes sense, thank you for this help.

Comment: If the starting record is always blank then it should be easy. Just create a blank gridview and store the data in a new record each time they save the form.

Comment: How do you add empty rows to a gridview? @obsidian

Comment: Just insert a blank textbox inside a template field!